# Error model language

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, spell-checking

I have to write a proper name spell checker.

I wrote the first part, the language model checker , but now there is the toughest part, 
the error model P(W|C) i.e. the probability that W would be typed in a text when the author meant C.

In order to solve it I came up with the easiest solution, the algorithm pick the word which has the smallest Damerau–Levenshtein distance, if there are more the one name the algorithm must pick the most common name.

The application works properly, though  I'd like to improve it. I'd like to introduce a e-learning machine algorithm which learns from the most common errors.
I must implement a machine learning algorithm.

So I've begun to think how to do that.

Into the error model language is it possible to find some pattern :

- It's most common to have misspelled letter in the middle of the word,
- it's easier to misspell a vowel with another vowel,
- ... so on...

I'd like to implement all these as fact.

In addition, this algorithm might be used for text recognition or voice recognition , therefore I have to consider :

- Homophones error such as, misspelling v for f is more common than misspelling v for q
- Typographical error such as, misspelling i for l or even finding ! inside the word.

To explain problem better: we may imagine this 2 scenario.

- First one is when the algorithm is used to read from  scanned sheets
- the other one is when the algorithm is used for voice recognition.

In the first scenario  errors such as letters with similar sound are more probable, while in the second one the typographical errors are more probable.
Since I don't know scenario in which my algorithm is going to work, I should implement a algorithm which dynamically adapts itself to the scenario, I mean if there is a error such as 
g!useppe  possibilities are giuseppe ( o.4) geuseppe ( o.6) 
the algorithm must pick the first because the shape of ! is similar to i and I have found a lot of similar errors.

I think the solution is a machine learning algorithm which learn from errors.

First question, did I explain my problem clearly ?
If so, which algorithm meets my requirements?

My experience with AI and machine learning is limited.

Comment: where would you get the training data?

Comment: I have a little file with some errors but I don't think they are enough to teach a machine how to dectect errors. 
However, when the application is started it loads in the memory a dictionary with all the names and its distribution percentage. 
Without training data, I should implement all the things I've said before as a rules?

Comment: Well, statistics without training data are tricky, but I think there should be some dataset containing common spelling errors freely available.

Comment: Here's [spelling error corpus](http://www.ota.ox.ac.uk/headers/0643.xml) it is actually referenced from [Peter Norvig's article](http://www.norvig.com/spell-correct.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard to pick the single most likely correct spelling, which is why most spellcheckers offer multiple options to choose from. I would suggest that you do so as well, if possible. One might even get away without any statistical learning at all -- just present the user with every possible valid name such that the edit distance between it and the input is below some given value N.